# How to drop packets based on length?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, linux-networking, ddos

could someone help to make iptables to drop all the packets with length 1006?

Example: 18:33:18.964261 IP 74.209.87.132.3054 > 126.220.67.183.13806: UDP, length 1006

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `length` match. It supports the range of length.

To drop all udp packets with length 1006 bytes:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m length --length 1006 -j DROP
```

**P.S.**

1. The `iptables -m length --help` shows the brief help of the `length` match.
2. Read [the iptables tutorial](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html) to understand of the basics.
3. Other rules and order of the rules are very important.
4. Better use the `iptables-apply` to safe change of the rule set (read the man).
5. To troubleshoot check the rule counters.
6. The tcpdump captures incoming packets before the iptables.

Comment: and how I can do if 74.209.87.132 is always changing?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi my friend, I have one more question, please
This is the output of tcpdump port <port> : 18:33:18.964261 IP 74.209.87.132.3054 > 126.220.67.183.13806: UDP, length 1006

The packet length is actually 1006? I have read on the internet this output does not show correct udp packet length